# Rounded corner, rectangle buttons

Tags: html, css, button

I am interested in making an html button similar to the ones found on the homepage of https://new.myspace.com/. I know that the html would look like this:

```
 <button class="button" id="join">Join</button>
```

Although I'm not sure on what the css should look like. I know there are many tutorials online about html buttons, but I'm not sure about semi-rectangular ones. Thanks, Harrison

Answer (score 9):

Use border-radius. The exact code in that example is `border-radius: 4px;`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius

Following Jake's good advices, use this catch-all-browser rules:

```
button#join {
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: But how would I apply that to a button?

Comment: Go to the css and add `input[type='button']{border-radius:4px;}`

Comment: Also, add `-moz-border-radius:4px;` and `-webkit-border-radius:4px;` to work on all browsers.

Comment: The standard name (`border-radius`) should come after vendor-specific versions. Also, `-webkit-border-radius` is typically not needed anymore. Lastly, the vendor-specific prefixes should start with `-`.

Comment: Editing but -webkit isn't needed in previous chrome or safari versions?

Comment: @martriay, safari 4 is the only reason to keep supporting -webkit-, but its been on safari 5 (and now 6) for a couple years now, so its probably safe to remove.

Comment: then I'll keep it, there are only 8 bytes and someone out there could be using safari 4

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<button class="button" id="join">Join</button>
```

Css:

```
.button {
    /*adjust the roundness*/
    border-radius: 4px;
    moz-border-radius: 4px;
    webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    /*adjust height and width*/
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px; 
    /*change border colour*/
    border:1px #245ec6 solid;
}
```

Adjust the amount of pixels the border radius property is in order to change how much it is rounded.

Edit: apparently the website you posted uses 4px (code adjusted)

Second edit: Adjustments made to the code to make larger buttons and to effect all buttons.

Comment: How would I make the button it self bigger?

Comment: @HarrisonHoward, Do you mean width or height? Make your code look like this: (change enter_height_here and enter_width_here accordingly: `input[type='button']{border-radius: 4px; moz-border-radius: 4px; webkit-border-radius: 4px;height: enter_height_here; width: enter_width_here;}`

Comment: @Bernie, you can just get rid of the id all together and just use `input[type='button']{}' or `button{}` in your case. Makes the code cleaner

Comment: @Jake Okay im using:     .buttons{
 border-radius: 4px; 
 moz-border-radius: 4px; 
 webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 height: auto; 
 width: auto;
 padding: 15px;
 
 background-color: #245ec6;
} but im not sure on how to make the grey background go away

Comment: I feel that using the id is much cleaner, if he wants all the buttons effected, use a class.

Comment: @HarrisonHoward, Have you made sure your button is using the class .buttons?

Comment: Yes, the color changes, but the blue takes effect, just not completely. See: http://pbrd.co/Wgx0A7

Comment: @HarrisonHoward, the button appears to be blue immediatly to me?

Comment: But not the outline of it. Did you see the picture?

Comment: Change the border color: `border:1px #245ec6 solid;`

Comment: @Jake Ahha! Dur. Thanks, i think thatll do for now

Comment: Edited it into my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little info on border-radius: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

And here's a cool little generator to make things easy: http://border-radius.com/